# authorisation failure in Pyramid (Python)

Tags: python, authentication, authorization, pyramid

So I'm trying to port some old Pylons code to Pyramid, and I'd like to be able to improve on the Auth setup - specifically support better RBAC, and Pyramid has good support for this.
However, I'd like to offer unauthorised users better info when they try illegal pages:

"Sorry, in order to view [page] you ([user]) need [group] privileges - please contact [admin]"

However I don't see how that's practical in Pyramid - I can do stuff in the forbidden_view_config page, however I can't easily find all the info needed from the page which was attempted - is it possible to get the exception or similar with the actual reason why permission was not granted?

Comment: Is your question, "Where do I get the 4 pieces of information that I want to display in the forbidden view?" Assuming that is the case, then you can get that from the request object. See https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/security.html for a good starting point for security related objects and methods.

Comment: I'm not sure where I'd easily get the 'page' or rather route_name and which permission is needed to access it? One thing I was considering was overloading ACLAuthorizationPolicy, so that the info was pushed onto the session for authenticated users - which would mean I could present it quite easily. If I'm about to generate the forbidden_view_config page, then how would I be able to find out which permission was required for the previous (attempted) page? I have the referrer from request, the user, but the required permission I can't seem to find + I'd prefer the route_name as its behind proxy

Comment: `context` is one place to get the object. The [request](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html) object itself should have all the other bits you need. Unless, of course, you redirect to another page.

Comment: Ok, but whenever a permission is lacking, won’t users automatically be redirected to the forbidden_view_config page, or is that page rendered instead of the forbidden one? I’ll have a look with the tutorial when I can.. - thanks!

Comment: No redirect, unless you tell your app to do so with `return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url("home"))`, for example. You should `raise HTTPForbidden()`. You can customize that however you like. Pyramid docs and the Community Cookbook have examples.

Comment: Cool, so I figured out that the request has an exception attribute, which in turn has a 'result' which is the ACLDenied exception - this contains the specific permission. for the [page] part, I've now settled at using the url % application_url - which should be fine in most cases I guess. want to drop an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [request](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html) object itself should have all the bits you need.

Specifically, [security-related pieces](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/security.html) lists some of the request attributes that you can retrieve. Also the [`request.exception`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.exception) attribute will be available when an exception is raised. There are several URL-related pieces available to get the "page", including [`application_url`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.application_url).